# error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]

Tags: c++

When I run the following code, I meet some errors from leetcode.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int findDuplicate(vector<int>& nums) {
        int n = nums.size();
        vector<int> dp(n, 0);
        for(auto num:nums)
            if(dp[num]==1)
                return num;
            else
                dp[num]++;
    }
};
```

solution.cpp: In member function findDuplicate

Line 5: Char 28: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]

```
vector<int> dp(n, 0);
                        ^
```

cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors

I have met the same error in some other questions before, thanks for your help.

Comment: if `dp[num]==1` is never `true`, then where does the function return?

Comment: if condition `dp[num]==1` will never be true then there will be no return statement executed, what is not clear?

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you in compiler message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `findDuplicate` to return an `int`.

If `dp[num]==1` is never true, then your function doesn't return an `int`. In that case the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Comment: actually it is the case when `nums` has no duplicates